# How to check active IDs from six months ago

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

How can I sum(ctc) in one line with a single statement that IDs from 1/1/2023 still exist on 6/1/2023? so I tried the below statement but returned 0!

```
SUM( CASE WHEN ID = LAG(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY GP ORDER BY Date- 5 MONTH) 
THEN SUM(FLOAT(value)) ELSE 0 END) AS count
```

I also tried this :

```
case when date = Date- 5 MONTH then 
        coalesce(
            lag(value) over(
                partition by id, case when date = eDate- 5 MONTH then 1 else 0 end
                order by date
            ),
            0
        )
    end  AS PrevValue
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nCaiLhDp) Link to sample data!

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're uisng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery like here:

```
WITH CUSTOMERS AS 
(
SELECT GP, ID, DATE(TO_DATE(DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) AS DATE, CTC
FROM
(
VALUES
  ('AAAA', '001', '1/1/2023', 1)
, ('AAAA', '002', '1/1/2023', 1)
, ('AAAA', '003', '1/1/2023', 1)
, ('AAAA', '004', '1/1/2023', 0)
, ('AAAA', '001', '6/1/2023', 1)
, ('AAAA', '002', '6/1/2023', 1)
, ('AAAA', '005', '6/1/2023', 1)
, ('AAAA', '006', '6/1/2023', 1)
) CUSTOMERS (GP, ID, DATE, CTC)
)
SELECT 
  A.*
, A.CTC +
  COALESCE 
  (
    (
      SELECT SUM(B.CTC) 
      FROM CUSTOMERS B 
      WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND B.DATE = A.DATE - 5 MONTH
     )
   , 0
  ) AS CTC_SUM
FROM CUSTOMERS A
```

| GP | ID | DATE | CTC | CTC_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAA | 001 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| AAAA | 002 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| AAAA | 003 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| AAAA | 004 | 2023-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| AAAA | 001 | 2023-06-01 | 1 | 2 |
| AAAA | 002 | 2023-06-01 | 1 | 2 |
| AAAA | 005 | 2023-06-01 | 1 | 1 |
| AAAA | 006 | 2023-06-01 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3mpW9cIF)